# Getting the entire HTML of a dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'd like to get the HTML of a DOM element that was dynamically created:

```
 var titleTag = document.createElement("h4");
 titleTag.innerHTML = 'this is a title';
```

How can I get the entire DOM element with tags?

```
<h4>this is a title</h4>
```

Comment: If I `console.log(titleTag)` I get `<h4>this is a title</h4>`. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kc85ntwo/

Comment: @DanielD That's the console's display formatting, though. Getting it as a Javascript string value is a (slightly) different matter. Try `typeof titleTag` to see this.

Comment: Ahh @lonesomeday that makes sense. I figured I had to be missing something there =). Thanks for that!

Comment: ya that's right in fiddle.  in my code, it always showin an empty tag <h4></h4>. very strange.

Comment: typeof(titleTag) outputs 'Object'

Comment: @user3681740 My only guess is that somehow or other you are not actually editing the relevant tag. Can you paste the actual current code at the bottom of your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is with [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML). This has historically been frowned upon, because it was custom Internet Explorer functionality that was not in any standards, but it is now widely supported and even in a W3C draft standard.

```
var HTML = titleTag.outerHTML;
```

Comment: I tried this solution, I only get '<h4></h4>'  without the text inside.

Comment: `outerHTML` is also referenced in the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/infrastructure.html), which is a recommendation.

Comment: @Oriol Really? Where? #curious

Comment: It's just a mention in [Common infrastructure](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/infrastructure.html) - [Conformance requirements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/infrastructure.html#conformance-requirements) - [Dependencies](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/infrastructure.html#conformance-requirements-dependencies) - DOM. Just below [event name](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/infrastructure.html#eventdef-global-name)

Comment: @Oriol Interesting - it's not *defined* as such. But this is splitting hairs: the point is that we can now use it and not feel worried!